# Xcode on windows for ios development

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

Is there a way to develop ios applications in windows?

How can i setup Xcode on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using VMWare on windows but for that you need to have Windows machine with good configuration.
But its having following drawback

1 You cant use latest MAC version

2 Its not possible to build app on device

3 and finally its very slow.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: thanks gaurav , can you please further explain, what components i have to install after installing vmware

Comment: You will get readymade VMWare files on any torrent, download it, extract and give this path to VMWare by creating new virtual machine from option.

Comment: @Daniel i just want to start coding , even if it is 70 - 80 % accurate then i will deploy application on my IPad and fix the functionality which is not accurate

Comment: @Gauravakasparsh can you please refer me any of such file that help me in setup, i searched alot but could't find any

Comment: @Daniel GNUstep doesn't have UIKit ready but Tanveer wants to develop software for iOS. GNUstep will not help that much.

Comment: When my mac was being repaired, I successfully used VMWare image on my windows and I could do everything there. The performance was not perfect so I was running my apps mostly on device and not in the simulator. And note this is not compliant with the MacOS license.

Comment: Only third point  is true and with a powerful system the third point is false as well

Answer (score 4):

This following information is taken from the [**following answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065343/why-isnt-there-xcode-for-windows/2065404#2065404) by mipadi written a few years ago. It is still relevant now:

> "Xcode is written in `Objective-C` and takes advantage of a number of
>   OS X frameworks, so porting it to Windows would require porting all
>   the frameworks on which Xcode relies..
>
> Also, Xcode also uses a number of programming tools that would have to
>   be ported to Windows as well (although some of them already are).
>
> There are multiple reasons why X-Code isn't readily available on
>   Windows:
>
> - Most development of Objective-C frameworks takes place on OS X, and
>     a lot of the frameworks aren't open-source and thus can't be ported
>     to Windows (they'd have to be rewritten).
> - There are some open-source frameworks that could be used on Windows
>     -- for example, OS X's AppKit and Foundation frameworks are (mostly) available as part of the GNUstep project -- but these
>     frameworks
>     aren't widely used or supported on Windows, and sometimes lack
>     capabilities found in their OS X counterparts."

It is also possible to use xCode on Windows via. a Virtual Machine; however, the result will not be what you want. It will be slow, and as you won't have access to many of the important frameworks, iOS development will be out of the question.

If you just want to program Objective-C on Windows as a means of learning the language, I advise downloading [**Codeblocks**](http://www.codeblocks.org/) - [**see this documentation**](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Objective-C_Compiler) in regard to configuring the Objective C Compiler on it.

Comment: This is pretty much the exact same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/2065404/921739. Look there for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use XCode on Windows. I tried a few months ago for 2-3 days to make it work on windows and i finally bought a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is not a suported platform for Apple, but some people seems to have found a workaround:

http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/installing-ios-sdk-and-xcode-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose only virtualising Mac on  windows pc is the way or get a [Hacintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/).