# Objective-C on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows

I have been programming a lot of C++ and I was interested in starting to program Objective-C.
However, I only have a PC that has Windows and Linux on it. Is it possible for me to program Objective-C without a Mac? Or is it mandatory to buy one?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637879/xcode-on-windows-for-ios-development

Comment: you mean objective-c?

Comment: @danh: That question is about XCode. You don't need XCode to program in Objective-C.

Comment: @DanZimm: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @DanZimm: It's a duplicate question, but I see no indication that the poster is a troll. The 1-point reputation implies that the OP likely isn't familiar enough with the site to know that it's a duplicate.

Comment: Originally it had "objectiff c" in the question and "objective-c" in the tag... seemed a bit fishy to me

Answer (score 0):

If you compile Objective-c under Linux or whatever you'll basically be learning the syntax of Objective-c, but you won't be learning how to really do anything useful with the iPhone or OSX.

Just buy a Mac.