# React Native expo create iOS app without mac?

Tags: iphone, react-native, expo

Can I develop for IO using React Native? I don't have mac or money to buy it. I have listen about expo.io which do it on there servers.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637879/xcode-on-windows-for-ios-development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use expo, then we build the iOS app for you on our machines. You can test the app on your local Android device.

Answer (score 1):

You need a macOS machine to build your application. On Expo, they have macOS machines that build your app. But now you can also build non-expo applications, by remotely accessing a macOS build machine as part of [Codemagic's product](https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/). Currently, you can get 500 build minutes for free per month.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Edgar's answer, you can easily test your application natively on iOS device if you just have an Apple developer account, you can refer to [this article](https://amressammohamed-95.medium.com/your-guide-to-testing-your-expo-react-native-application-on-ios-abbde4086d08) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

React and Expo allow you to write your application in javascript. Thus, you will be able to develop your app that will eventually work on an ios device.

However, to test the app locally before you publish it you have two options: 
1. Use a mac to spin up ios simulators.
2. Directly scan the barcode from the expo app to test your app on an actual IOS device.

Answer (score -3):

My below report is based on case study finished in March 2019

We have compared both EXPO and React native for mobile application development

EXPO is great tooling and makes application development life cycle extremely easier but it doesn't support many features which might be a requirement for today's enterprise.

My case study shows that it can't do following important features -

Screen recording
Bluetooth
WebRTC
No Support of handling push notification in background
No support for third party push notification services
No support for NFC
No Audio playback in background
Many permissions being needed despite the fact the device doesn't use them
No in app purchase
For large apps loading time is large
Large memory snapshot
Large application size
No native code
No native plugins only expo API

What is good for -

As of today it's good general mobile application which does't use too many native device features. Also good for application which as of today doesn't have long terms road map to use core device features.

It's also great at quick start mobile application development as EXPO provide single api's support for both for ios and android.