# XCode installed software on windows 7?

Tags: iphone, xcode, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t there Xcode for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065343/why-isnt-there-xcode-for-windows)

I want to use the software XCode for iPhone development.

I do not have mac computer, is there a way to do this on windows7?

Comment: It's not possible because XCode is Mac only. You may try to install VMWare on your PC and create a virtual machine running Mac OS X in it.

Comment: Where can I get this download?

Comment: @DavidFang: IIRC it is not allowed (although possible) to install Mac OS X in a VM.

Comment: Why vote down? This is a legitimate question, I just wanted a good answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot Mac OSX on Windows OS system using dual boot option, please refere this [link](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/04/how-to-dual-boot-mac-os-x-and-windows-7-complete-work-through/).